# Laravel deleting old image after updating

Tags: laravel

I want my user's old image to be deleted when they update it. This current function does not work how I want it. How would I change it so it works?

```
 public function update($id)
        {
            $profile = Profile::findOrFail($id);
    
            $data = request()->validate([
                'title' => 'required|max:255',
                'image' => ''
            ]);
    
            if ($profile->image) {
                if (Storage::exists("storage/{$profile->image}")) {
                Storage::delete("storage/{$profile->image}");
              }
}
                
            if (request('image')) {
                $imagePath = request('image')->store('profile', 'public');
                $image = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"))->orientate()->fit(1000, 1000); //Intervention Image Package
                $imageArray = ['image' => $imagePath];
                $image->save();
            }
        
    
            
            // $profile->image = $request->image; //Lägg till senare
            
            $profile->update(array_merge(
                $data,
                $imageArray ?? [],
            ));
    
    
    
            return redirect("/profile/{$profile->user_id}");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to take the old image and delete it from the server

```
  if (file_exists(('./images/partners/' . $partner->image_path))) {
                unlink(('./images/partners/' . $partner->image_path));
      }
```

after that you can upload your new image and update the record in the database

Comment: Okay, it seemed to work when not using the Storage function, thanks!